# Replace Expensive Transformer with cheaper alternative?

Tags: transformer, repair

I have a range hood that has an expensive (IMO) transformer that has went bad.  Here is the link to the transformer that went bad: http://www.repairclinic.com/buy/1/14238-transformer-oem-5304464262.html

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could replace this transformer with a cheaper alternative?  Would something I have around the house have a transformer in it that would work?  Could I buy something broken on craigslist and take it out?  Would Lowe's or Home Depot carrry something that would work?

As you can see it is a 120v to 12v transformer. And something went wrong? [image]

Comment: Before you replace the transformer, figure out why the device on the heatsink made that burn mark on the inside of the case. The transformer failure might be a secondary effect. (No pun intended :-)

Comment: I think OP is referring to replacing the entire device as 'transformer' in contrast to the brown and ferrite core transformer that I initially thought was meant. The whole device is called 'electronic transformer'. Would be good if OP clarified what he means by 'transformer' in his question and at the same time indicate specifications other than 12V and 1120V

Comment: All the specs are listed on the link.  That is why I didn't list them all out.

Comment: @Kyle Rogers So we're supposed to click on the link, spend time looking on the page for specifications, figure out that there aren't any and then read what the sticker on the image of the part says because you couldn't be bothered to type it out? That seems a bit rude to me.

Comment: @KyleRogers Can you describe the diagnostic method by which the transformer was determined to be bad? The transformer is just that brown coil surrounded by the black iron square.

Comment: @Kaz You are correct, I have no idea that the transformer is the problem.  When I first posted this today I assumed the entire piece was the "transformer".  Apparently this is a multitude of parts that I'm unfamiliar with.  All I know is 120v goes in and 24v comes out and it should be 12v.

Comment: It's quite possible, I would say likely, that the transformer is actually good, which means that someone who knows what they are doing could probably fix this thing inexpensively.

Comment: @Kaz You have any idea what I would look for in the yellow pages or internet searches for this sort of expertise?

Comment: Look for an electrician that does "appliance repair"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you replace a safety-critical component, the onus is on you to ensure that you're not violating any regulations or local laws.

[image]

Based on your link, the transformer that failed has a big backwards UR mark on it, which means its an Underwriters Laboratories recognized component. Most likely the safety certification of the entire hood relies on this one piece of equipment.

If you improvise something, or try to fix it yourself, or replace it with a 'cheaper' alternative, beware: if something goes wrong you're responsible and most likely wouldn't get any insurance money for it either. My advice: replace it with the same part or get a new hood.

For what it's worth, the features listed on the label: thermal protection, short circuit protection and your picture make it clear that it's more than just an AC transformer in there. I see a bridge rectifier, some capacitors, possibly a sleeved inductor along with the transformer. There's probably some housekeeping going on in there along with the step-down functionality.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  Perhaps you are correct and I shouldn't gamble with safety.